# PostgreSQL file handling and directorys

Tags: database, postgresql, ftp

When I work with PostgreSQL and files (e.g. to copy the content of a file to a table), the file has to be stored lokaly on the computer that hosts the database. Is there any chance to change this?

If I use the following code to copy the content of a .csv file, the path refers to the computer that host the database.

```
     Using cmd = New NpgsqlCommand()
         Using conn = New NpgsqlConnection("Host=" & c_dbHost & ";Username=" & c_user & ";Password=" & c_password & ";Database=" & c_DBName)
             conn.Open()
             Using writer = conn.BeginTextImport("COPY tbl_test(value) FROM 'C:\temp\test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;")
             End Using
         End Using
     End Using
```

I have a frontend that creates temporarily .csv files. Their content has to be stored in the database.

What is the common way?

The only possibility I see is to install a ftp server where the frontend sends the .csv files to, but I would prefer, that the content is stored in the database on the fly without saving the created .csv in a ftp folder which is reachable from the database server.

Answer (score 2):

Most client drivers support a wrapper around the `COPY` protocol, allowing you to `COPY ... FROM STDIN` via the client driver.

nPgSQL is no exception, see [the documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html).

You appear to be halfway there, since you've used `conn.BeginTextImport`. I imagine you just didn't realise you can specify `FROM STDIN`, and then loop over the returned `writer` to write rows from a local CSV file.